# Difference between mapped unit and target unit

Tags: soilgrids

I am looking to use the SoilGrids REST API to fetch [soil properties](http://rest.isric.org/soilgrids/v2.0/docs#/default/query_layer_properties_properties_query_get).

The coordinate inputs for lon-lat are (-72,-9). Some of the soil properties show two units of measurement - mapped units and target units. Can anyone please help me in understanding why I am seeing two different units for one property? Which one is correct and what is the rationale behind showing two units?

Sharing a snippet from the API response below.

```
{
  "name": "ocd",
  "unit_measure": {
    "d_factor": 1000,
    "mapped_units": "g/dm³",
    "target_units": "kg/dm³",
    "uncertainty_unit": ""
  },
```

Comment: If this is open data then the place to ask about its attributes may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

All maps produced with SoilGrids store data as integer values to minimise storage space. Therefore, some properties are provided in units that are not so common in soil science. By dividing the predictions values by the values in the Conversion factor column, the user can obtain the more familiar units in the Conventional units column.

You can find more information in the table in [this section](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#What_do_the_filename_codes_mean)

The target_units of the REST correspond with the conventional units in the table.